# Create a Python loop to find start and stop values

Tags: python, loops, date

I want to create a list with dates when the following happens to the data in Python.

- First time when the number is below 4.0
- First time that the number reaches 0
- First time that the number is back above 4.0

I gave a sample dataset in the table below. However, this happens multiple times and that is where I am struggling. I tried a for-loop to create the data but it only gives back the first time that this occurs, while I am interested in all events.

Sample data set:

| Date and Time | Process value |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-06-07 00:00 | 8.2 |
| 2020-06-07 01:00 | 6.5 |
| 2020-06-07 02:00 | 4.3 |
| 2020-06-07 03:00 | 3.6 |
| 2020-06-07 04:00 | 0 |
| 2020-06-07 05:00 | 0 |
| 2020-06-07 06:00 | 0 |
| 2020-06-07 07:00 | 3.2 |
| 2020-06-07 08:00 | 4.8 |
| 2020-06-07 09:00 | 0 |

Expected result:

| Date and Time | Process value |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-06-07 03:00 | 3.6 |
| 2020-06-07 04:00 | 0 |
| 2020-06-07 08:00 | 4.8 |
| 2020-06-07 09:00 | 0 |

Any tips?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fun way to do this one:

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
  "Date and Time": ["2020-06-07 00:00", "2020-06-07 01:00", "2020-06-07 02:00", "2020-06-07 03:00",
                    "2020-06-07 04:00", "2020-06-07 05:00", "2020-06-07 06:00", "2020-06-07 07:00",
                    "2020-06-07 08:00", "2020-06-07 09:00"],
  "Process value": [8.2, 6.5, 4.3, 3.6, 0, 0, 0, 3.2, 4.8, 0]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[Shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to find previous values:

```
below_4 = (df["Process value"] < 4) & (df["Process value"].shift(1) > 4)
above_4 = (df["Process value"] > 4) & (df["Process value"].shift(1) < 4)
reach_0 = (df["Process value"] == 0) & (df["Process value"].shift(1) != 0)
df.loc[below_4 | above_4 | reach_0]
```

Yields:

```
      Date and Time  Process value
3  2020-06-07 03:00            3.6
4  2020-06-07 04:00            0.0
8  2020-06-07 08:00            4.8
9  2020-06-07 09:00            0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remember state.

```
result = []
last_event = "init"

for item in items:
    if last_event == "init" and item["value"] < 4.0:
        result.append(item)
        last_event = "below_4"
    elif last_event == "below_4" and item["value"] == 0:
        result.append(item)
        last_event = "is_0"
    elif last_event == "is_0" and item["value"] > 4.0:
        result.append(item)
        last_event = "above_4"
```

Normally, you'd define the possible states separately in a dict or dataclass, so that new states are not randomly introduced across a larger program.